# Google map+spreadsheet not working in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-maps, google-sheets-api

Check this URL [Google Map+spread sheet](http://www.cibolacreative.com/gmaps/ranchoverdeArea.html). This is working well in my all browsers, and my all friends all browsers too, But this is not working on client's IE (IE8).
Client sends us an screen shot where Gmap is loaded but not the spreadsheet data.
I'm not getting what is the problem? :(
I tested it in all environments like IE6-7-8-9 on all OS win98-xp-2003-vista-win7.

Comment: Loads fine for me. You may have to try and re-create the client's problem, or debug the problem on their PC (with an eye on the error console)

Comment: Thanks Pekka, It will be good if i could this, But client is far away from me. :(

Comment: Finally, I'm using XML file instead of G-spreadsheet and making request to it and plotting data on map. And it's working ... :)

Answer (score 0):

For me, in IE it shows the spreadsheet but not the map and it gives a js error. fixing it should help.

```
Webpage error details


Message: Invalid character
Line: 1
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://maps.gstatic.com/cat_js/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/3/5/%7Bcommon,util,infowindow%7D.js


Message: Invalid character
Line: 1
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://maps.gstatic.com/cat_js/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/3/5/%7Bmap,style%7D.js


Message: Invalid character
Line: 1
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://maps.gstatic.com/cat_js/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/3/5/%7Bmarker%7D.js
```

Comment: IE is sometimes tricky and annoying...it might be a problem with one of the versions. I've had problems too. I'd also check what's causing the error. Maybe you can correct/change something and it will work on all browsers.

Comment: I used IE8 btw...and got those errors. What version have you used for testing?

Comment: I'm Using IE8 too. and checked in all other browsers. And the errors above listed are not in files i can access.